# How to use enum values as state diagram states?

Tags: uml

I want **state diagram states to be values of given enum type**. In the second step I'd like to use the state diagram as constraint for a property of previously mentioned enum type, e.g. as argument check in the property's setter.

Comment: I've found there is Redefined Classifier attribute in the model, it looks it could be the answer but I'm not sure yet.

Comment: Can you clarify your question please. Do you mean: "how do I implement the state diagram such that only legal transitions among values of the enum are allowed?".

Comment: I've edited the original question to calrify it, I hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not sure I completely understand what you're trying to achieve.  Here's some thoughts however, hope they're useful.  Apologies if I've missed the point.

The first question is: why do you want the enum values and states to be isomorphic?  In the most general sense that's replicating information.  And replicated information has a habit of getting out of sync.  So it would be useful to understand the motivation.

Notwithstanding, here's a couple of possibilities.

**1. UML / Modelling perspective**

In the UML world there's no real need to have both a state model and an enum associated with it.  UML in general doesn't define how to read the value of an object's current state; however certain profiles (e.g. [Executable UML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_UML)) do.  In Executable UML, any class that has a state machine automatically gets a read-only attribute named `current_state`.  The possible values for `current_state` are the names of the states in the state model.  So you could view it as the state machine defining an implicit enum.

Note the attribute is read only.  That's because the only way to change it is through the state machine, i.e. by sending events to the object.  So it also satisfies your second requirement: it's not possible to change the value of the `current_state` variable in a way that violates the state machine protocol.

Even if you're not using the Executable UML profile (or similar) it's perfectly valid to state the above as a rule/convention.  If necessary you could define your own profile, although that might be overkill - depends on your circumstances.

The key point is the enum isn't necessary in the modelling world.

**2. Code Perspective**

When Translating the model to code, an enum is a sensible and common way to define the type for the current state variable.  Per the modelling scenario, you'd want to make the `current_state` attribute read only to the outside world.  You then need three other things:

1. An implementation of the state machine
2. public member functions for each of the events that drive the state machine
3. A private member function for updating the `current_state` variable from within the state machine implementation.

So in the code world, you prevent invalid sequences of the `current_state` variable by making it read only to the outside world.  That is, you only have a public read accessor: there's no public write accessor.

Inside the class, you make the write accessor private and ensure the only place it gets called is within the state machine implementation.

Instead of a public write accessor, you provide public methods corresponding to the events that drive the state machine.  More detail on implementing state machines below, but here's a trivial example for now:

```
class Phone {

    enum PhoneState {disconnected, connecting, connected, disconnecting};

    public PhoneState current_state {get};  //no write accessor

    //functions for generating state machine events
    public void digit(int number) {..}      //press digit key, e.g. while dialing
    public void connect() {..}    //make connection
    public void disconnect() {..} //disconnect
}
```

**Implementing the State Machine**

There are 3 common patterns for implementing state machines:
1. State Matrix or Lookup Table
2. Nested Switch
3. State Pattern

There's a good overview of (1) [here](http://www.conman.org/projects/essays/states.html); (2) & (3) are covered [here](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/umlfsm.pdf).

And that's basically it.  Not entirely sure I answered your question.  If not apologies, perhaps you could be more specific about what you're trying to achieve.

hth.

Comment: Although it does not solve my 'problem' it is really good overview and I've got some directions for further study.

Comment: Sorry it did't answer your question.  Maybe you could elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

enumeration properties are represented in UML like this:

```
_______________________
|   <<enumeration>>   |
|    DaysOfTheWeek    |
|_____________________|
| Sunday              |
| Monday              |
| Tuesday             |
| ...                 |
|_____________________|
```

Then you can just draw an association between the enumeration and your state diagram.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your implementation in details but I would redirect you to the state machine pattern, a very elegant way to implement state machines. Cf, the wikipedia page:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern

Answer (score 0):

In some tools you can click on the enum > Create state diagram. It means that the state diagram will be create at the root of the enum in the UML model tree. The state diagram would therefore have the enum property.

Comment: Sounds interesting by the tool I'm trying to use (TOPCASED, based on Eclipse) does not have such option or I can't see it. Still, your answer helps me to look at it from different angle.